# Add an Organization to existing hyperledger fabric network, with different org will run in different physical machine

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have using the link http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-rc1/build_network.html for building the network. In this it is running two organization Or1 and Or2 in a single physical machine.

I want to add two different organization in to my fabric network where both the organization will be run in different physical machine. 
For example: Org1 in machine1 and Org2 in machine2

Please help how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need docker swarm to co-ordinate the communication between the two hosts which run the org docker containers .

Reference - https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f

There will be more flavours in the future depending on kubernetes vs docker swarm.

Comment: Thank for your response,I have already tried this link, but in this it is using 2 different peer for one organization. **Org1 having 2 peer peer0 and peer1**. And both the peer is running in different machine.

But I want to add Org2 with peer2 in a different machine.

Comment: I believe it wont differ much, can you share a github repo of your attempt. I can give it a shot when i have time.

Comment: I am using same steps and example mentioned in that link only. Can you suggest, what additional I have to do to add an organisation?